# Writing to Registry type REG_MULTI_SZ

Tags: registry, jscript

I am trying to write to the Registry using Jscript. 
I am able to do this [command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b(v=vs.84).aspx) for REG_SZ, but it doesn't support REG_MULTI_SZ.

How can I write to the Registry using Jscript when the Registry I am trying to change is of type REG_MULTI_SZ?

```
var WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
var regPath = "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\PROGRAM\\ProgramName";
var newVal = "com.settings=changed";
var regType = "REG_SZ";

WshShell.RegWrite (regPath, newVal, regType);
```

Comment: Try using Penton.RegObject  http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/registry-reading-and-writing-made-simple-part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not end up using Penton.RegObject. but that link did send me to finding a solution.

instead I did [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162(v=ws.11).aspx) to change the REG_MULTI_SZ:

```js
        var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

        var commandtoRun = "reg.exe "; //"C:\\Windows\\System32\\reg.exe ";
        var regPath = "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\PROGRAM\\ProgramName";
        var newVal = "com.settings=changed\\0com.user=newUserName\\0";

        var args = "ADD \""+regPath + "\" /v Options /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "+newVal;

        objShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,args);
```